# Java Swing Read PDF Return Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/bouncycastle/asn1/ASN1OctetString

Tags: java, swing, itext

I am creating one desktop based application where i can read PDF and show content in Preview Page.
I am using itext and icepdf library for this task but when reading pdf file by below code

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(pdfFilePath);
```

and it is returning below exception

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/bouncycastle/asn1/ASN1OctetString
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfEncryption.<init>(PdfEncryption.java:149)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader.readDecryptedDocObj(PdfReader.java:1013)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader.readDocObj(PdfReader.java:1411)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader.readPdf(PdfReader.java:721)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader.<init>(PdfReader.java:181)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader.<init>(PdfReader.java:219)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader.<init>(PdfReader.java:207)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader.<init>(PdfReader.java:197)
    at com.pdf.common.services.PDFMain.createLeftPanel(PDFMain.java:316)
    at com.pdf.common.services.PDFMain.<init>(PDFMain.java:444)
    at com.pdf.common.services.PDFMain$1.run(PDFMain.java:155)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:251)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:733)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1OctetString
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    ... 25 more
```

i have tried below jar files as per google searches

[image]

but everytime i got same error

Comment: You have different versions of the same library on your class path. That generally won't work, in particular not with BouncyCastle. Determine the version you need and only put that into your class path.

Comment: For iText 5.5.13: BouncyCastle 1.49, as can be seen in the `pom.xml`.

Comment: @mkl actually i havent use all that version for same library. when i use lower version of itext library(5.5.0) at that time i use lower version of bc****** library(1.49) and when i use latest version of itext library(5.5.13.1) at that time i use latest version of bc****** library(1.66)

Comment: @AmedeeVanGasse ok let me test with your provided version library

Comment: @AmedeeVanGasse thank you very much.. its now working properly

Answer (score 1):

I have solved my issue by using below version of library

```
iText 5.5.13,
BouncyCastle 1.49
```